# How to use enum for singleton design pattern?

Tags: java, enums

I understand that the following piece of code always gives same instance always and also can not be modified and is best recommended for single/multi-threaded use.

```
enum Colors {
    RED, BLUE, GREEN;
}
```

But I want to know how to use **enum** for applying singleton pattern to custom classes, I mean where we normally do initializations and then return instance. Citing an example will be of great help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Singleton Pattern: Using Enum Version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23721115/singleton-pattern-using-enum-version)

Comment: But it still does not answers on possible initializations to create the instance.

Comment: An enum can have a constructor. You do the initialization there.

Comment: Don't - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/179392

Comment: @bayou.io That answer is wrong, as noted in the comments.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede - the number of "sophisticated serialization or reflection attacks" on singletons is greatly exaggerated :) it's a strawman.

Answer (score 1):

You can do encapsulation and initialization just like you do in a class.

Here's a simple example:

```
public enum Color{
  INSTANCE(10, 30, 50);

  private int red, green, blue;  

  private Color(int red, int green, int blue){
     this.red = red;
     this.green = green;
     this.blue = blue;
  }

  public int getRed(){
     return red;
  }

  public int getGreen(){
     return green;
  }

  public int getBlue(){
     return blue;
  }
}
```

In this case you have a thread safe singleton instance of the enum type Color.

Comment: Keep in mind that enums are designed for storing constants or in other words a list of objects that belong to one type. If you want a thread safe singleton, then make your singleton initialization class threadsafe by using the keyword synchronized.

Comment: If fields are not final and setters are present, then in enums too, synchronization needs to be applied just like normal classes to make them thread-safe?
And does enum, by default, only have the property of singletons, as they are not affected by visibility of constructor to outer world.