# Another way to program "static": Is Code ok?

Tags: java, static

I need some advice about how to structure of my java applications.  Personally I like to decide - like for example in python or C++ - if I program OO or not. For me, static is a way to do the same in Java.

I read, most people say static is "evil". So I thought of another option of doing the same you do with static.

What about creating a class called "StaticClasses" containing an instance of each class, which methods/attributes normally would be static.

I could create one instance of `StaticClasses` and set a reference to this instance in each object I create.

I could even create a new object-class `mObject`, which is the new parent-class of everything - directly after Object to set up these references.

And: I could make the `StaticClasses` class a Singleton.

Just small code examples, so you know what I mean:

```
// mObject.java
public class mObject{
    static StaticClasses staticCl = StaticClasses.I;
}

// StaticClasses.java
public class StaticClasses{
    public static StaticClasses I = new StaticClasses();

    // declare instance of each "static" class
    public Example0 ex0 = new Example0();       
    public Example1 ex1 = new Example1();

    private StaticClasses(){
    }
}

// Example0.java
public class Example0 extends mObject{
    public void do_something(){
        System.out.println("function call example 0");
    }
}

// Example1.java
public class Example1 extends mObject{
    public void do_something2(){
        // class "static" function
        staticCl.ex0.do_something();    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        // call "static" function
        staticCl.ex1.do_something2();
    }
}
```

Is this a good or a really bad idea? Do you know any improvements? Do you know disadvantages of this code? Static should have slightly better performance, but shouldn't make much difference. Or should I manually set up references where I need them - even if this means more complicated code.

UPDATE:

You don't like the singleton. New Code without singleton (names are not final):

```
// mObject.java
public class mObject{
    Classes cl;
    public mObject(Classes c){
        cl=c;
    }
}

// Classes.java
public class Classes{
    // declare instance of each "static" class
    public Example0 ex0 = new Example0(this);       
    public Example1 ex1 = new Example1(this);
}

// Example0.java
public class Example0 extends mObject{
    public void do_something(){
        System.out.println("function call example 0");
    }
}

// Example1.java
public class Example1 extends mObject{
    public void do_something2(){
        // class "static" function
        cl.ex0.do_something();    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        // call "static" function
        cl.ex1.do_something2();
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't call it `StaticClasses` if they're not static.

Comment: This is an extension of the [constant `interface` antipattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_interface) to use a [God object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) to hold your singletons. You are avoiding one Java "edict" (`static` is evil) by creating something truly hideous.  I would **strongly** suggest you avoid this pattern like the plague. If something needs to be a singleton, use the [`enum` singleton pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23721155/2071828). I would further suggest you read about DI - which is recommended instead of global state.

Comment: why do you redefine the instance "I" of "StaticClasses" again in mObject while you can access it already through StaticClasses.I?

Comment: It may be more beneficial to you if you were to explain your reasoning for wanting to use static generally and this pattern specifically.

Comment: @shmosel yeah; names are not really good

Comment: @Boris the Spider: Would it be ok, if I didn't use Singleton?

Comment: `static` is evil if you use it to do evil things you are not supposed to do with it. Same can be said for a knife, we still need the knife to cut our bread though. We can choose to be stubborn about it and not to use knives at all, thus using our own hands to tear the bread, but doing so is cumbersome and most likely will leave us with a sub-par slice of bread anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a lot of complication for zero benefit.  You can make a singleton instance and throw some inheritance at it, but in the end you cannot whitewash away the fact that you're still calling a static method.

Java allows static methods as a way to let you write code that is not 100% object-oriented.  For example, `Math.sin(0.5)` is perfectly fine; you don't want to have to write something like `new Double(0.5).sin()`.  The advice to avoid static methods is not dogma that you need to follow — it's a general warning that you might want to consider a more object-oriented approach.  Your scheme doesn't help make things any more object-oriented at all, so it's a misguided effort.

Comment: thanks for your answer; I updated my code, so there's no singleton any more. Think a benefit might be, if something unexpected happens and I somehow need to create a second instance.

Comment: Still, that is probably a very inappropriate use of inheritance. (I can't tell for sure, with your hypothetical names.)

Comment: Sorry, but one last question: Creating a class just to hold other objects is ok, isn't it?

Comment: Maybe. I suggest that instead of asking in hypothetical generalities, you post a question on [codereview.se] with a concrete use case that solves a real problem. Then we can evaluate whether your approach is appropriate. Please read [How to Ask](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) first to make sure that you post the right kind of question.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to answer on an academic example. *Static is evil* is a general rule, and as any general rule it may have exceptions. One is the singleton pattern where the singleton object is a static variable in its class accessed through a static method. Take large well known projects like Spring Framework, and you will see that they do use static.

Static is considered evil because it is often used when another object or class would be more appropriate. A common example is the students in a university. The university name is common for all students and first idea is to make it static in student class, as for other parameters for the university. And now as the program is genial you want to extend it to another university ... and all crashes because university is static in student class : you should have a university class and an object of that class (not static) in student class

Another example would the number of objects in one class. It is generally better to have a factory object that count them than a static field : what if you later want to count separately two kinds of objects ?

For your current question the best answer is in  Boris the Spider's comment : *You are avoiding one Java "edict" (static is evil) by creating something truly hideous*.