# Using enum as factory vs static factory method

Tags: java, enums, singleton

Good day,

I have extracted my object creation into a factory.

The standard way of doing it in the project is by using static factory method.

```
public final class CustomerFactory {

    private CustomerFactory(){}

    public static Customer valueOf(Detail detail) {

        Customer customer = new Customer();

        String name = detail.getName();
        customer.setName(name);
        String lastname = detail.getLastname();
        customer.setLastname(lastname);
        customer.setFullname(name + " " + lastname);

        Date age = detail.getAge();
        customer.setAge(age);

        return customer;
    }
}
```

From looking at the code, I can see the constructor is private and the class is final. The class cannot be instantiated or extended i.e. `new` or `extends`

I decided to make a enum Factory which does the same. Why? One cannot extend it, no need for final on class level and no need to have the private constructor.

```
public enum CustomerFactory {

    INSTANCE;

    public Customer from(Detail detail) {

        Customer customer = new Customer();

        String name = detail.getName();
        customer.setName(name);
        String lastname = detail.getLastname();
        customer.setLastname(lastname);
        customer.setFullname(name + " " + lastname);

        Date age = detail.getAge();
        customer.setAge(age);

        return customer;
    }
}
```

Upon reviewing by a peer it was decided that it should go back to the original because it is the wrong use of a `enum` and also singleton pattern.

For me there is no difference between the two implementations, I would rather choose the one that is cleaner i.e no need to code extra access modifiers

Is the below a misuse of a enum as it is intended only to be used for constants?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, if one solution could achieve its goal, it's not a misuse, but it may not be the best practice. To be honest, it's the first time for me to see using enum as factory pattern. Like your peer said, enum is usually used for grouping constants or used for singleton pattern. When using enum:

**Advantage:** no `final` and no `private` constructor.

**Disadcantage:** the call of enum is longer than original way. That is, now we write `CustomerFactory.CREATE.form(userDetail)`, but in the original way, we just write `CustomerFactory.form(userDetail)`. So, the original way is much **cleaner** and **easier to understand**.

I'd rather prefer using the original way.

Comment: I did a bit of research before the implementation, found the stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23721115/singleton-pattern-using-enum-version

Comment: @Rentius2407 Yes, we usually use enum for singleton pattern. In your question, you said using enum for factory pattern, not singleton pattern. Factory pattern will create different objs with each factory method call as enum pattern will always get the same obj.